# Wrappers size reflecting its contents

Tags: css, html

[Take a look at this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kWJ79/1/).

I'm puzzled as to why `#wrapper` doesn't expand to accommodate the divs inside it. What's missing here?

As a side note, any idea as to why my `<hr>` isn't displaying properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wrapper doesn't expand because the items inside are floating and taken out of the natural flow of the document.

You can tell the wrapper to expand past the floating elements by adding a block level element to the end of the wrapper and telling it to clear all floats:

```
#wrapper:after{
  content:".";
  display:block;
  clear:both;
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

Also, you had the height of the wrapper set to 100px.

Here's an updated version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kWJ79/9/

As for your `hr`, what exactly are you wanting to do? It looks like you're wanting to create a vertical bar between the 2 divs. Is this correct?

**UPDATE**

If you're wanting to create a line between the left and right divs I'd consider a slightly different route.

What I'd do is put the left div inside its own container which has a right padding, margin and border. This way you don't have a redundant div floating around in your code and recudes the need to use a hr.

Here's an updated fiddle with this example: http://jsfiddle.net/kWJ79/15/

```
#left_wrapper{
    margin-right:5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    border-right:1px solid red;
    float:left;
}
```

Notice that I've removed the `float:left;` from the `#left` div and placed it on the `#left_wrapper` instead.

Comment: Also will have to remove the height on the #wrapper, otherwise the above won't work.

Comment: Thanks pleunv. I must have updated just before your comment :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, very useful. I originally had the vertical rule as a border but decided to change it because I thought it was unorthodox. Looks like it'll be fine!

Comment: One more thing - is there a way I can do this horizontally as well?

Comment: Oh, and also: I'd like the vertical rule to go to the bottom of the page. This page is going to contain dynamic content so it is unclear whether in any instance the left or right column will be longer. Can this still be done as a border?

Answer (score 1):

You have specified the height value.