# Create horizontally aligned divs in another div

Tags: html, css-float

I want to create some html.
In a div, which has a grey border, there should be two divs horizontally aligned. There should be a separating line between them.

```
<div style="width:400px; border-color:#D3D3D3; border-style:solid; border-width:1px;">
<div runat="server" id="plDiv" style="width:300px;">
    one
</div>
<div style="border-left:1px; border-left-style:solid; border-left-color:#D3D3D3; width:100px;">
    other
</div>
```

I excluded all my tries to use float because it just doesn´t do what I want. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div style="width: 400px; border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;; overflow: hidden;">
  <div id="plDiv" style="width: 300px; float: left;" runat="server"> one </div>
  <div style="border-left: 1px solid #D3D3D3; width: 99px; float: left;"> other </div>
</div>
```

When the second div has a width of 99px (to take into account the border I assume) then the floats seem to work fine.

Comment: I think that the border width is added to the width of a div (on the outside).  So when you had 300px + 100px + 1px (border-left) the total was 401px and so they could not fit side by side within a 400px wide div. Is this what you are asking?!

Comment: but if I change width to 500px it doesn´t change. overflow:hidden seems to be the key?!

Comment: `overflow-hidden` forces the container div to stretch to contain the floated divs inside it. There are other ways to do this, but this is the one I am in the habit of using.

Answer (score 1):

See the answer I just posted here a few moments ago:

[Wrappers size reflecting its contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734315/wrappers-size-reflecting-its-contents/6734354#6734354)

This does exactly what you're asking.

Basically there are 2 divs inside a container and a dividing line between the two:

You can see this demonstrated here in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kWJ79/15/